# ImageMagick on Windows XAMPP Starts but Cannot Read Files

Tags: xampp, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to read a local file with imagick running on XAMPP:

**File location on my PC:**

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/www/iustlab/app/uploads/references/2019/12/24/f-193.pdf
```

**PHP code:**

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(300,300);
// Reads image from PDF
$imagick->readImage("C:/xampp/htdocs/www/iustlab/app/uploads/references/2019/12/24/f-193.pdf");
```

**Error message**

```
Message: PDFDelegateFailed `Impossible to find the specified file.' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/79477
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Your path looks wrong. I would first try putting the file in the same folder as the code and try that: $imagick->readImage("f-193.pdf"); You should be able to work with relative paths.

Comment: Did you install Ghostscript on your machine? You need this to read the pdf file.